# Angular 2+ HttpErrorResponse not returning correct status for a timeout

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

So I'm using httpClient.get() to make a REST call. I've set up the API to return a time out 504.

When looking at the Google devTools I can see that the call is made and the status is 504. but when I debug my code the HttpErrorResponse I get has status 0.

I also set up the API to return a 400 response and when I debug that code the Response status was 400. Why is the 400 propagated but the 504 is not?

We are using Angular 6.0.6

Answer (score 1):

Better way of doing is to implement Error Handler.
In my case I have a common class to make HTTP calls and all the services (ex: EmployeeService, SupplierService etc) will communicate to common API to make Rest API calls. Below is the sample code which handle the error. Here is what you will see if HTTP Status code is 404.

> Server side Error - Code: 404
>   Message: Http failure response for http://localhost:5000/apiv1/account: 404 Not Found

Here is my Common Service looks like.

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ApiService {

  getUrlvalue: string;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


  private formatErrors(error: any) {
    let errorMessage = '';
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      errorMessage=`Client side Error: ${error.error.message}`;
    } else {
      errorMessage=`Server side Error - Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
    }

    console.log(errorMessage);
    return throwError(error.error);
  }


  get(path: string, params: HttpParams = new HttpParams()): Observable<any> {
    //console.log(`${environment.api_url}${path}`);
    this.getUrlvalue = `${environment.api_url}${path}`;
    console.log('API service get request is making to : ' + this.getUrlvalue);

    return this.http.get(this.getUrlvalue, { params })    //, { params }
      .pipe(  
      catchError(this.formatErrors)
    
      );
  }

  put(path: string, body: Object = {}): Observable<any> {
    console.log(`${environment.api_url}${path}`);
    return this.http.put(
      `${environment.api_url}${path}`,
      JSON.stringify(body), httpHeaderOptions
    ).pipe(catchError(this.formatErrors));
  }

  post(path: string, body: Object = {}): Observable<any> {
    console.log(`${environment.api_url}${path}`);
    return this.http.post(
      `${environment.api_url}${path}`,
      JSON.stringify(body), httpHeaderOptions
    ).pipe(catchError(this.formatErrors));
  }

  delete(path): Observable<any> {
    console.log(`${environment.api_url}${path}`);
    return this.http.delete(
      `${environment.api_url}${path}`
    ).pipe(catchError(this.formatErrors));
  }

}
```

From other service link AccountService this is how it's call for simple HTTP Get

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AccountService {

  // private http: HttpClient
  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }

  getAccounts(): Observable<Deal[]> {

    return this.apiService.get('/account')
      .pipe(
        tap(deals => console.log('fetched Accounts 111111')),
        catchError(this.handleError('getAccounts', []))
      );
  }
```

Comment: We do have an errorHandler implemented. The problem is in the response the error status is 0 instead of 504.

Comment: Not sure what is the issue is. I have just returned the Status 504 from my Web API and it works fine for me. Can not attach screenshot in comments.

Comment: I am able to get it to work if I create a fresh app and fake the 504. So I know it "works." It just doesn't work in my app.

Comment: Base on your questions, i do not have enough facts to know what is causing the issue. Suggestion: Examine your response header to see whether your Service returns the correct Status in the event of timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out our API Gateway wasn't set up correctly and we weren't returning the correct headers.

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST,GET,OPTIONS',
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 
'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token',
```